# Can't Get ng-repeat To Work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have been practicing AngularJS and Angular Material. and I have followed tutorials where I utilized ng-repeat. I am trying to do this on my own but I can't seem to get it to work. I do not have any console errors. I don't see what could be missing so I may be missing an important concept in Angular. Thank you for your help!

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/31WaRmH5RRdW5TFEFbg2

**HTML**

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
<title>Angular Material</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/v0.8.3/angular-material.css" />
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.15"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular-aria.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/v0.8.3/angular-material.js"></script>
<!-- ICON SET -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material-icons/0.7.1/angular-material-icons.min.js"></script>

<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="controllers.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <md-list flex>

      <md-item ng-repeat="artist in artists">
      <a>
        <md-item-content md-ink-ripple layout="row" layout-align="start center">
          <div class="inset">{{ artist.name }}
          </div>
        </md-item-content>
      </a>
    </md-item> 
</md-list>

</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
                                 'ngMaterial',
                                 'ngRoute',
                                 'ngMdIcons',
                                 'artistControllers'
                                ]);
```

**controllers.js**

```
var artistControllers = angular.module('artistControllers', []);

artistControllers.controller('ListController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
    $http.get('data.json').success(function(data){
        $scope.artists = data;
    });
}]);
```

Comment: When you don't use any routeing you need to specify the controller on one of the elements using [`ng-controller`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController)

Comment: This is also a very useful comment. I originally was trying to use routing from one of the tutorials I used and it wouldn't work. So I began this from scratch to detect the problem and leave routing behind in the meanwhile. Now I understand why my routing wasn't working in another test. Thank you!

Comment: When you use routeing you normally don't need to specify the ng-controller tag, instead, you need the [ng-view](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView), if you have a look at the example on that page it might help ☺

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed [ng-controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController) to include in the element.

```
<md-list flex ng-controller="ListController">
```

[**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/3hWnuoY6waKQRZKoovRo?p=preview)

Comment: Ah, I'm so mad at myself! Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. Silly mistakes eats a day sometimes. Haha :P

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `ng-controller`

```
<body ng-controller="ListController"> 
</body>
```